# Cotangent complex and lci morphisms

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

I am a bit confused by the relevant literature I am aware of on the subject (Quillen, Avramov, etc.), so I would like to ask the following question to more expert people than me.

[The question has been edited below using Damian and Unknown's comments, and actually split into two different ones.]

Let $X$ and $Y$ be schemes over a field $k$, and let $f: X\rightarrow Y$ be a morphism locally of finite presentation.

Consider the relative cotangent complex $L_{X/Y}$ of $f$ as a cochain complex in non-positive degrees.

$Question$ $1.$ Suppose we know furthermore that

(a) $\mathbb{L}_{X/Y}$ is perfect,

(b) $\mathbb{L}_{X/Y}$ is of perfect amplitude in $[-n,0]$, for $n>>0$.

Does it follows that $\mathbb{L}_{X/Y}$ is of perfect amplitude in $[-2,0]$ ?

$Question$ $2.$ Suppose we know furthermore (i.e. in addition to (a) and (b)) that

(c) $f$ is of finite Tor-dimension,

Does it follows that $\mathbb{L}_{X/Y}$ is of perfect amplitude in $[-1,0]$ ?

Note that I am not assuming any Noetherian property for $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: I think that you need to assume that $L_{X/Y}$ is a perfect complex and $Y$ noetherian for this to be true. Quillen's conjecture assumes perfectness and noetherianity.

Comment: To Damian: thanks, you are certainly right about perfection of the cotangent complex (edited). On the other hand, my question was exactly about *not* having the schemes to be noetherian. Are there known  counterexamples in this case?

Comment: The problem is local so you may assume that $X$ and $Y$ are affine. You may then write the morphism as a limit of morphisms of finite type to spectra of noetherian rings (see for instance EGA IV.3 Prop. 8.9.1). On the hand, the homology of the cotangent complex is compatible with limits in this sense - see Quillen, "On the cohomology..." (4.11), so the result follows.

Comment: Great, Damian, thanks! I'll check the Quille & EGA details.
If it works, the same proof also give a stronger statement (coming from a stronger statement by Avramov): replace the second condition on the relative cotangent complex
by '' the relative cotangent complex has tor-amplitude in $[-n, 0]$, for $n>>0$ '', and replace the conclusion by '' Then the relative cotangent complex has actually tor-amplitude in $[-1,0]$ ''.

Comment: Alright, keep me posted...

Comment: On second thoughts, I see that there is a gap in the reasoning I outlined above: it is not clear that you can reproduce the hypothesis "perfect" on the finite level (ie on the noetherian approximations). It is not obvious to me that you can; this is perhaps where the whole difficulty lies. 

Comment: I think the induces are slightly off. For example, the ring map $k[t]/(t^2) \to k$ has a perfect cotangent complex with a non-trivial $H^{-2}$.

Comment: @unknown (google): you are right; there is still one hypothesis that is missing: $X$ has to be a of finite tor-dimension over $Y$ (also in Quillen Conjecture 5.7 in "Cohomology of commutative rings"). 

Comment: Thank you to both! I guess I'll edit the question according to your comments, hoping to set it in a more reasonable shape. But it will still be a question :)

Comment: @unknown (google): the example is nice, its cotangent complex lives in degrees $[-3,0]$ and is perfect (and you can actaully compute it,using that it is an algebra retract); the morphism is finitely presented but not of finite tor-dimension. If it might help in setting the landscape, there is an example (by Planas-Villanova) of a ring morphism $f:R \rightarrow k$ where $k$ is a field, such that the cotangent complex of $f$ has vanishing $H^{-2}$ and non-vanishing $H^{−3}$. Of course R is non noetherian, and the map is not finitely presented (so it is not a counterexample to Question 2).

Comment: @Gabriele: That's interesting! Can one do better? I mean, are there examples of surjective maps $A \to B$ with $H^i L_{B/A} = 0$ for $i > -n$ for some fixed n, but $L_{B/A} \neq 0$ ?