# When is the cotangent complex perfect?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, derived-categories, derived-algebraic-geometry, cotangent-complex

Let $X\rightarrow S$ be a proper flat morphism of schemes.

When is the cotangent complex $L_{X/S}$ perfect ?

It is well known, that for local complete intersections the cotangent complex is perfect, but are there examples where perfectness still holds without the lci assumption ?
And if there are examples, is there some general theorem which deals with perfectness in the non-lci case ?

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/114282/cotangent-complex-and-lci-morphisms

Comment: I would guess you just need locally of finite presentation

Comment: Avramov's theorem already answers the question: for flat maps, we have lci <=> perfect cotangent complex (over a noetherian base). Relatedly, being locally finite presentation is way too weak (take any non-lci variety).